# Tile Grid for Sentinel -1

Tags: tiles, sentinel-1

I'm new with GIS.

I would like to know if there is a defined tile grid for Sentinel-1.

For Sentinel-2 images, there is a defined grid with UTM code, Latitude band and Square.

There is something like this for Sentinel-1?

If not, how can I find out which images contains the polygon that I need to analyse?

We are going to use the AWS sentinel bucket to download the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sentinel 1 products do not use a a tile grid. However, to identify products over your polygon you can use one of several Sentinel 1 search/download resouces. This is not an exhaustive list by any means.

ESA offer the [SciHub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home) which allows searching by drawing a polygon area of interest (AOI). You have to create an account (free) before you can search and download the products. A [User Guide](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/GraphicalUserInterface) is also available.

The Alaskan Satellite facility's [Vertex](https://vertex.daac.asf.alaska.edu/) tool is another good resource and allows you to draw an AOI or enter specific coordinates. They provide interactive tours of the tool.

Alternatively, ESA do provide information on the Sentinel 1 [acquisition segments](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-1/observation-scenario/acquisition-segments) in KML format - you could download the segment for the dates you are interested in and view alongside your AOI.

If you still want to download via AWS these resources will give you enough information about the products over your AOI to enable you to find them on AWS.

GitHub user Kersten has put together a [list](https://github.com/Fernerkundung/awesome-sentinel#data-access) of all things Sentinel, including more resources.